Terminal is taking hours to install Next.js what to do?
I have started learning coding few weeks ago. I had installed Next.js yesterday and it run smoothly then deleted the project. Today when I again tried to install, its been more then four hours and still its loading.

I uninstalled Visual Studio and again created different project but still nothing is working.

I would skip PowerShell and just use the Git Bash. You can specify a logging level with npx e.g. --loglevel verbose

thank u Mr. Polywhirl. After uninstalling and re installing vs, I am able to create next.js for my project. Here the issue could be, my pc is slow or this time I created my project folder later with terminal. If further issue arises I would defiantly use Git Bash.

I faced many other technical problems in terminal after my previous comment, later I figured out, it was the editor which was the problem. I was using "Visual Studio" instead of "Visual Studio Code". Hope that helps someone.

Yeah, Visual Studio is typically used for C/C++/C# development.
